# Resharper 8: Use ContractAnnotationAttribute for validation method

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a method to validate a RegEx:

```
private string _value;
private void ValidateFormat(RegEx pattern)
{
  if (!pattern.IsMatch(_value)
    throw new Exception("...");
}
```

Now ReSharper marks the `pattern` argument as "Parameter 'pattern' is only used for precondition check(s)".
Searching the Internet I found a solution to use the ContractAnnotationAttribute (see [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/08/15/contract-annotations-in-resharper-7/) and [here](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/439602)).

But I still can't get it to work for this specific case.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to get anything to help here. The `ContractAnnotation` attribute can be used to mark a method as an "assertion" method, meaning the whole point of the method is to assert something and throw if it fails. This can help with analysis, such as removing the precondition check, but also telling calling code that passing null will produce dead code, etc.

Unfortunately, the precondition you're checking here is complex, and can't be modelled in the `ContractAnnotation`. My advice is to ignore ReSharper's warning, either by doing nothing, or telling ReSharper to disable the warning for that piece of code (alt+enter, suppress with comment)

Comment: Thx. I think there was an AssertionMethod attribute in earlier versions of ReSharper that did the trick. So I think there has to be a way to do it with ContractAnnotation, hasn't it?

Comment: I think you can still use `[AssertionMethod]`. Get the latest JetBrains.Annotations package from nuget (it's the official one) and I'm pretty sure it's in there.